# ECC - EDAC_DRIVER is not set message

Tags: drivers, 18.04, ram, edac

Bionic LTS server

I have a Ryzen processor and AsRock motherboard, both run ECC with no issues.

The problem I am having is in `syslog` I see `Not enabling Memory Error Detection and Correction since EDAC_DRIVER is not set`:

```
root@localhost:/home/one# dmesg | grep edac
[    4.858773] EDAC MC0: Giving out device to module amd64_edac controller F17h: DEV 0000:00:18.3 (INTERRUPT)
[    4.858781] EDAC PCI0: Giving out device to module amd64_edac controller EDAC PCI controller: DEV 0000:00:18.0 (POLLED)
root@localhost:/home/one# cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i edac
Oct 15 20:50:34 localhost systemd-modules-load[502]: Module 'edac_core' is builtin
Oct 15 20:50:34 localhost systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Initialize EDAC...
Oct 15 20:50:34 localhost edac[832]:  * Not enabling Memory Error Detection and Correction since EDAC_DRIVER is not set
Oct 15 20:50:34 localhost edac[832]:    ...done.
Oct 15 20:50:34 localhost edac[832]:  * Loading DIMM labels for Memory Error Detection and Correction edac
Oct 15 20:50:34 localhost kernel: [    0.156551] EDAC MC: Ver: 3.0.0
Oct 15 20:50:34 localhost kernel: [    4.858684] EDAC amd64: Node 0: DRAM ECC enabled.
Oct 15 20:50:34 localhost kernel: [    4.858685] EDAC amd64: F17h detected (node 0).
Oct 15 20:50:34 localhost kernel: [    4.858719] EDAC MC: UMC0 chip selects:
Oct 15 20:50:34 localhost kernel: [    4.858720] EDAC amd64: MC: 0:     0MB 1:     0MB
Oct 15 20:50:34 localhost kernel: [    4.858720] EDAC amd64: MC: 2:     0MB 3:     0MB
Oct 15 20:50:34 localhost kernel: [    4.858721] EDAC amd64: MC: 4:     0MB 5:     0MB
Oct 15 20:50:34 localhost kernel: [    4.858721] EDAC amd64: MC: 6:     0MB 7:     0MB
Oct 15 20:50:34 localhost kernel: [    4.858723] EDAC MC: UMC1 chip selects:
Oct 15 20:50:34 localhost kernel: [    4.858723] EDAC amd64: MC: 0:     0MB 1:     0MB
Oct 15 20:50:34 localhost kernel: [    4.858724] EDAC amd64: MC: 2: 16383MB 3: 16383MB
Oct 15 20:50:34 localhost kernel: [    4.858725] EDAC amd64: MC: 4:     0MB 5:     0MB
Oct 15 20:50:34 localhost kernel: [    4.858725] EDAC amd64: MC: 6:     0MB 7:     0MB
Oct 15 20:50:34 localhost kernel: [    4.858725] EDAC amd64: using x8 syndromes.
Oct 15 20:50:34 localhost kernel: [    4.858726] EDAC amd64: MCT channel count: 1
Oct 15 20:50:34 localhost kernel: [    4.858773] EDAC MC0: Giving out device to module amd64_edac controller F17h: DEV 0000:00:18.3 (INTERRUPT)
Oct 15 20:50:34 localhost kernel: [    4.858781] EDAC PCI0: Giving out device to module amd64_edac controller EDAC PCI controller: DEV 0000:00:18.0 (POLLED)
Oct 15 20:50:34 localhost kernel: [    4.858781] AMD64 EDAC driver v3.5.0
Oct 15 20:50:34 localhost edac[832]:    ...done.
Oct 15 20:50:34 localhost systemd[1]: Started LSB: Initialize EDAC.
```

In /etc/modules I placed `edac_core`. I also see ECC is enabled in the kernel:

```
root@localhost:/home/one# cat /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-29-generic/.config | grep -i edac
CONFIG_EDAC_ATOMIC_SCRUB=y
CONFIG_EDAC_SUPPORT=y
CONFIG_EDAC=y
# CONFIG_EDAC_LEGACY_SYSFS is not set
# CONFIG_EDAC_DEBUG is not set
CONFIG_EDAC_DECODE_MCE=m
CONFIG_EDAC_GHES=y
CONFIG_EDAC_AMD64=m
# CONFIG_EDAC_AMD64_ERROR_INJECTION is not set
CONFIG_EDAC_E752X=m
CONFIG_EDAC_I82975X=m
CONFIG_EDAC_I3000=m
CONFIG_EDAC_I3200=m
CONFIG_EDAC_IE31200=m
CONFIG_EDAC_X38=m
CONFIG_EDAC_I5400=m
CONFIG_EDAC_I7CORE=m
CONFIG_EDAC_I5000=m
CONFIG_EDAC_I5100=m
CONFIG_EDAC_I7300=m
CONFIG_EDAC_SBRIDGE=m
CONFIG_EDAC_SKX=m
CONFIG_EDAC_PND2=m
root@localhost:/home/one# cat /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-29-generic/.config | grep -i ecc
CONFIG_HAVE_ARCH_SECCOMP_FILTER=y
CONFIG_SECCOMP_FILTER=y
CONFIG_SECCOMP=y
CONFIG_MTD_NAND_ECC=m
# CONFIG_MTD_NAND_ECC_SMC is not set
CONFIG_MTD_NAND_ECC_BCH=y
CONFIG_AMD_XGBE_HAVE_ECC=y
CONFIG_MTD_SPINAND_ONDIEECC=y
```

What is causing `Not enabling Memory Error Detection and Correction since EDAC_DRIVER is not set` and how do I fix that?

UPDATE: output from edac-utils

```
root@localhost:/home/one# edac-util -v
mc0: 0 Uncorrected Errors with no DIMM info
mc0: 0 Corrected Errors with no DIMM info
edac-util: No errors to report.
```

Comment: Have you installed the `edac-utils`?  It is not installed by default.  It might help.  `sudo apt install edac-utils`  I don't have access to a server at home right now, so I won't be much more help beyond that.

Comment: Yep, but didn't help. Also, I need to make a correction.... the driver error is from syslog, not dmesg.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message

```
* Not enabling Memory Error Detection and Correction since EDAC_DRIVER is not set
```

is a needlessly scary message from the edac init script (part of the edac-utils package). What it's telling you is that it is not manually loading a specific edac kernel module because the variable $EDAC_DRIVER is not set in /etc/default/edac. You can see this from the relavant bits of the init script:

```
   if [ -n "$EDAC_DRIVER" ]; then
     log_daemon_msg "Enabling ${DESC}" "$SERVICE"
     modprobe $EDAC_DRIVER
     STATUS=$?
     case $STATUS in
       0) log_end_msg 0 ;;
       5) log_failure_msg "No EDAC support for this hardware"; log_end_msg 1 ;;
       *) log_failure_msg "failure with exit code $STATUS"; log_end_msg 1 ;;
     esac
   else
      log_daemon_msg "Not enabling ${DESC} since EDAC_DRIVER is not set"
      log_end_msg 0
   fi
   log_daemon_msg "Loading DIMM labels for ${DESC}" "$SERVICE"
   $edac_ctl --register-labels --quiet
```

Given that the kernel is automatically determining which edac driver to apply and the $edac_ctl command (immediately following the if-then-else block that checks whether $EDAC_DRIVER is set) successfully registers the DIMM labels, it looks to me like everything is functioning correctly here (but, full disclosure, I don't know anything specifically about EDAC).